# How do I evaluate a Xpath expression using Saxon on .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, saxon

How do I evaluate for following Xpath expression in .net using saxon? I need to be able to pass in a variable and to get the result in one full set of code.

```
SchematronTestText = "not(count($CTR17) > 0)"
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is just an artificial example: but it's equivalent to `empty($CTR17)`, and since $CTR17 is going to have to be supplied as an `XdmValue`, you can actually determine whether it is empty without going to the trouble of evaluating an XPath expression, using `XdmValue.Count==0`.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your response as I know you are the prime developer. This unfortunately is not an artificial example but an example of some assertions I am looking to repurposing on mass. In working through this code how would I set the variable to empty to get the Count ($CTR17) = 0 as true?

Comment: You can just assign the variable to XdmEmptySequence.INSTANCE.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: [PUT ON HOLD AS TO BROAD] I disagree. The question is about the use of Saxon in xpath in .net. The Michael are appreciated as he is the  architect of the software and has allowed me to progress through to the Answer which I posted. In the end anyone with a similar need can now find this snippet which can help them progress. I have provided more clarity to the original question.

Comment: Warwick, if you don't want the SO thought police rejecting perfectly sensible questions, you are welcome to use the Saxonica forums and bug trackers at http://saxonica.plan.io.

Comment: Yes Thank you Michael I will do that. One day though I will post something on this forum that one of these folks won't shut down. I am determined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Processor processor = new Processor(true);
XPathCompiler compiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();
compiler.DeclareVariable(new QName("aaa"));
XPathSelector selector = compiler.Compile("not(count($aaa) > 0)").load();
selector.SetVariable(new QName("aaa"), new XdmAtomicValue('sample')); 
var result = selector.EvaluateSingle().ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Michael when using the saxon9ee trial (9.7.0.6) the methods were in lowercase. Could I have picked up the wrong version?

Comment: Saxon on Java uses the Java convention of method names starting with lower-case; on .NET it uses the .NET convention of starting with upper-case. Otherwise the two interfaces are very similar.